# Use MySQL procedure to change the name of a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure to change the name of an existing table by appending the date to it.

I have only been using MySQL for a short while and cannot see why the code is not working.  I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0 Community to connect to the MySQL database and run the code.  In Workbench no errors are returned when I run the code.

The code I have managed to find so far is:

```
DELIMITER \\

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_test_dynamic_sql`\\
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_test_dynamic_sql`()

BEGIN

SET @s = concat('ALTER TABLE MyDashboardTable RENAME TO MyDashboardTable_',replace(date(now()),'-',''));

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;

END\\

DELIMITER ;
```

I have run part of the code, to find what @s is being set to by running:

```
SET @s = concat('ALTER TABLE MyDashboardTable RENAME TO MyDashboardTable_',replace(date(now()),'-',''));
select @s;
```

I have then pasted the result for @s

```
ALTER TABLE MyDashboardTable RENAME TO MyDashboardTable_20200904
```

This does change the name of the table but I cannot figure out why the stored procedure does not.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works for me - can you show how you are calling the SP and where you are doing this (locally, in a fiddle, aws) and please confirm you have privileges to run SPs

Comment: Also works https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j4HQpgVkSSoE7UQA1gNXS8/0

Comment: I am running it in a query window in workbench, on my local machine, with a vpn connection to the network the server is in.  I am running the script rather than executing the SP.

Comment: I have just executed the SP in a query window and received the following error: 15:23:30 execute usp_test_dynamic_sql Error Code: 1243. Unknown prepared statement handler (usp_test_dynamic_sql) given to EXECUTE 0.031 sec

Comment: I'm not sure what the end goal is but maybe partitioning would accomplish the same thing you are trying to do with procedures?

Comment: My goal is to rename the current live table by appending the date to it and then recreate the live table, with the original name and insert data into it

Comment: ' I am running the script ' - what script?

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer, the script is the script that creates the SP.  I have since tried just executing the SP by running EXECUTE usp_test_dynamic_sql and this is now returning the error 15:59:45 execute usp_test_dynamic_sql Error Code: 1243. Unknown prepared statement handler (usp_test_dynamic_sql) given to EXECUTE 0.031 sec

Comment: I tried  your SP in Workbench and it works fine! Most likely your issue it's related to 'script'.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your SP as

```
CALL usp_test_dynamic_sql();
```

You may also want to modify your

```
replace(date(now()),'-','')
```

with

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d')
```

Even though it's not absolutely necessary. If you do, do not leave spaces or use '-' or '/' between the formats since MySQL with throw an error.

Comment: Ah thank you, it was how I was running the SP, as I said I am new to MySQL and thank you as well for the dateformat tip.

Comment: And what's the script your were mentioning ? " I am running the script rather than executing the SP"